# I need to splite a column of dataframe into rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some dataframe that contains a column with a sequence of data I need to split it into multiple lines.

example:

```
import pandas as pd

example = { 'Name': ['Tom', 'Bob', 'Harry'],
         'Age': [22, 21, 24],
         'Basket' : ['bread%milk%cake%candies', 'water%orange', 'candies']}
       
df = pd.DataFrame(example)

Name    Age Basket
0   Tom 22  bread%milk%cake%candies
1   Bob 21  water%orange
2   Harry   24  candies
```

I need to obtain a table like that :

```
Name    Age Basket
0   Tom 22  bread
1   Bob 21  water
2   Harry   24  candies
3   Tom 22 milk
4   Tom 22 cake
5   Tom 22 candies
6   Bob 21 orange
```

I need help to find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[0, 1, 2], 'foo', [], [3, 4]],
                   'B': 1,
                   'C': [['a', 'b', 'c'], np.nan, [], ['d', 'e']]})
>>> df
           A  B          C
0  [0, 1, 2]  1  [a, b, c]
1        foo  1        NaN
2         []  1         []
3     [3, 4]  1     [d, e]
```

In your case, you first need to properly format the text data into list and then use `explode` feature.

```
import pandas as pd

example = { 'Name': ['Tom', 'Bob', 'Harry'],
         'Age': [22, 21, 24],
         'Basket' : ['bread%milk%cake%candies', 'water%orange', 'candies']}

df = pd.DataFrame(example)

def text_parser(text):
    # Transforms `a%b%c` to `['a', 'b', 'c']`
    # For `a` as input (No change)
    if text and '%' in text:
        return text.strip().split('%')
    else:
        return text

# formatting `Basket` columns
df.Basket = df.Basket.map(text_parser)

# splitting the columns into multiple rows
df = df.explode(['Basket'])

# reset index & dropping old index
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
del df['index']

print(df)
```

output

```
    Name  Age   Basket
0    Tom   22    bread
1    Tom   22     milk
2    Tom   22     cake
3    Tom   22  candies
4    Bob   21    water
5    Bob   21   orange
6  Harry   24  candies
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the values in the `Basket` column to lists and then use `explode`.

```py
import pandas as pd

example = { 'Name': ['Tom', 'Bob', 'Harry'],
         'Age': [22, 21, 24],
         'Basket' : ['bread%milk%cake%candies', 'water%orange', 'candies']}
       
df = pd.DataFrame(example)
df['Basket'] = df['Basket'].str.split('%')
df = df.explode(['Basket'])

print(df)
```

Output

```
0    Tom   22    bread
0    Tom   22     milk
0    Tom   22     cake
0    Tom   22  candies
1    Bob   21    water
1    Bob   21   orange
2  Harry   24  candies
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution

```
flatdata = pd.DataFrame([(index, value) for ( index, values)
                             in df['Basket'].str.split('%').iteritems() for value in values],
                             columns = ['index', 'Basket']).set_index('index')

df = df.drop('Basket', axis = 1 ).join(flatdata)
```

Output will be

```
Name    Age Basket
0   Tom 22  bread
0   Tom 22  milk
0   Tom 22  cake
0   Tom 22  candies
1   Bob 21  water
1   Bob 21  orange
2   Harry   24  candies
```